# Поменять стили для тэга vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify

уважаемые форумчане . Хочу поменять стили для тэга vuetify v-data-table . Как мне этого добиться через css?

```
 <v-data-table
        :headers="dataSecretsTableHeaders"
        :items="dataSecrets"
        :items-per-page="5"
        class="table"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
          <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(item)"
          >
            edit
          </v-icon></v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы указали `class="table"`.

Обращение в CSS будет примерно такое `.table .v-table %selector%`

Например покрасить `tbody` таблицы

```
.table .v-table tbody {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Таким образом можно обращаться к любому элементу внутри таблицы `th`, `td`, `tr` и т.д.

Так же внутри `<template></template>` можно задавать отдельные классы и обращаться к ним по такому же принципу.

Обращение через указанный класс нужно чтоб обратиться к конкретной таблице, если в одном компоненте используется много таблиц, если же таблица всего одна, то можно отбросить `.table` и писать просто `.v-table tbody`

P.S. Для "правильной" работы желательно чтоб в `template` были `<tr>`и `<td>`, иначе использовать `v-data-table` особого смысла нету

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что такое %selector%:?

Comment: @AdickSinelnikov Я так обозначил место, куда нужно подставлять какой-либо элемент таблицы, т.е. вместо `%selector%` нужно писать какой-то существующий элемент таблицы и стили будут к нему применяться.

Comment: Может я что-то не так делаю? Вот допустим я хочу поменять стили для :headers="dataSecretsTableHeaders".. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: @AdickSinelnikov `thead` таблицы содержит `tr` (ряд) и `th` (ячейка-заголовок). Например задать фон для заголовков 
`.table .v-table thead {
   background-color: red;
}`
Обращение в самим ячейкам-заголовкам (не знаю правильного названия) будет выглядеть так:
`.table .v-table thead th {
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: white; 
}`

Comment: Можно в браузере нажать ПКМ по таблице и выбрать "Исследовать элемент", там будет видно какие элементы содержит таблица, и уже из кастомизировать через CSS